# Get an object from the QListWidget and delete it

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qlistwidget

I have a qt and cpp application that creates threads on create button and runs them with a certain start time specified by the user. It list the thread object created into a QListWidget in the application with some random id generated. I can select and delete the QListWidget item as shown below.

```
  void MainWindow::on_stopPushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << mythread->threadIdGenerator();
   
    QList<QListWidgetItem*> items = ui->threadWithId->selectedItems();

    foreach(QListWidgetItem* item, items){
        ui->threadWithId->removeItemWidget(item);

  
        delete item; // Qt documentation warnings you to destroy item to effectively remove it from QListWidget.

    }
}
```

This delete operation just deletes the entry from the UI (QListWidget) of the application but the thread deleted from QListWidget is still running in the application.

My question is how can I get terminate this thread with deletion from the QListWidget from the UI of the application?
Or is there any way to get this thread object and delete it after being selected from the UI.

### Update

```
    void MainWindow::on_createNewThreadButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug(" in create new thread slot");
    mythread = new MyThread(this);
    mythread->threadOccuranceTime =  ui->insertThreadTimeoutHere->text().toInt();
    mythread->start();
    myThreadListCreatedObjects.append(mythread);
    connect(mythread, SIGNAL(signalForThreadMessage(int)), this, SLOT(displayThreadMessages(int)));
    connect(mythread, SIGNAL(sendThreadId(int)), this, SLOT(displayThread(int)));
}
```

### MyThread.cpp

```
int MyThread::threadIdGenerator()
{
    qDebug(" in threadIdGenerator function");
//    qDebug() << 1 + (rand() % 100);
    srand(time(0));
    return 1 + (rand() % 100);
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    this->threadId = 0;
    qDebug() << this->threadId;
    qDebug(" in run function for the thread");
    this->threadId = this->threadIdGenerator();

    qDebug(" id inside the run method of thread");
    qDebug() << threadId;
    emit sendThreadId(threadId);
    while (1) {
        msleep(this->threadOccuranceTime);
        emit signalForThreadMessage(this->threadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: qt docs suggest the following syntax
`QList<QWidget *> list;
...
while (!list.isEmpty())
    delete list.takeFirst();` for cleaning up a [QList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) while deleting the items

Comment: [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) documentation has various examples of how to connect signals to delete a thread when it's finished, you could emit resultReady on the thread or connect some other signal to that ... just as an idea. It also has information on managing threads.

Comment: We have no information about how you are running the threads. E.g. do they have event loop or not? Are their event loops busy or idle at the time when you are about to delete them? Overall this is not an easy task, this can be very very complicated, especailly if you need to first gracefully abort working threads first.

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager I have updated the manner in which I am creating the threads in the application, there are no Ideal threads (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: The application also crashes If I try to create too many threads.

Answer (score 0):

I used QList to store all the threads created, and when a item is selected in the QLIstWidget I tried to get the thread with that id property, terminate it and then remove from the QListWidget from UI as shown below.

```
   void MainWindow::on_stopPushButton_clicked()
{
    QList<QListWidgetItem*> items = ui->threadWithId->selectedItems();

    foreach(QListWidgetItem* item, items){
        qDebug() << "the item selected to delete";
        qDebug() << item->text();
        ui->threadWithId->removeItemWidget(item);

        QString selected = item->text();
        QString subString = selected.mid(0,2);
        qDebug() << "subString = ";
        qDebug() << subString;

        for(MyThread *sp:myThreadListCreatedObjects){

            qDebug() << "thread id = ";
            qDebug() << sp->threadId;
            if(sp->threadId == subString.toInt()){
                qDebug() << "subString = ";
                qDebug() << subString;

                sp->terminate();
                delete sp;
            }
        }
        delete item; // Qt documentation warnings you to destroy item to effectively remove it from QListWidget.
    }
}
```

I am not sure this is the correct way of doing the things but it works some how. Any better solution is welcome :).